# how to select an LDO regulator to get 3.3 v 200 mA of output from 5v and 250 mA of Input?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design, voltage-regulator, circuit-design, power-electronics

I would like to power my stm32 microcontroller the supply voltage is 3.3v and 160 mA of current. So i would like to regulate my buck controller output of 5v to 3.3v to power my microcontroller.

**My input to LDO regulator:**

**input voltage :** 5v

**input current :** 250 mA

**Expected output:**

**output voltage :** 3.3v

**output current :** 200 mA ( to power my STM32 microcontroller)

Iam planning to use Texas instrument TPS730 LDO regulator to get 3.3 v as output.

TPS730 power consuption:

(Vin-Vout) *Iout = (5v-3.3v)*200 mA = 0.34 W

In datasheet Maximum junction temperature is given as 150 degree C and Rthja as 225.1 degree C/W

so 225.1 *0.34 = 76.54 (degree C) + 25 (room temperature) = 101.54 degree C

so i think it is safe to use based on Power consuption. if iam wrong correct me whether it is safe or not.

**My doubts:**

i need an out put voltage of 3.3v and 200 mA of current but in datasheet it is given like 
[image]

What does this means . only if my output voltage is 5v then only i can able to get 200 mA as output current.If it is like this i cannot use this regulator because the maximum output voltage i need is 3.3 v so can i able to get 200 mA of output current with 3.3 v of output voltage if my understanding is wrong please correct me.
**or can i able to get 200 mA of current by having 3.3 v as output voltgae**

[image]

and What does this means i am confused.Is it telling like only if my input voltage is 5.5 v then only i can able to get 200 mA. if it is like this i cant use this regulator because my input voltage is 5v .Is it like that or can i use this regulator with 5v of input to get 200 mA of output

**Iam really confused after a large number of search i am asking this question in stack. Can i able to use this regulator by having 5v as input and i need 3.3 v output voltage and 200 mA of output current.**

**Please find the Datasheet of Texas instruments TPS730** [enter link description here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps730.pdf)

In the above datasheet in Page 13 it has given the adjustable output voltage .

**Basically can I use this regulator based on my specifications ,If no is there any regulator based on my specs with decent power consuption.**

Comment: Tip: 'V' for volt.You can also use HTML entities `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;`, `&times;`, etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts (but they don't work in the comments).

Comment: If you have new information you should edit your existing question, don't ask a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

The regulator output current range is from 0 to 200mA. So you can use it for a 200mA max load. 160mA is within range of 0 and 200mA.

The regulator output voltage range can be set between Vfb and 5.5-Vdo. Since 3.3V is included in the range, you can set it to output 3.3V.

Your previous question already covers that the regulator can have 3.3V output with 5V input quite easily because the difference is much larger than minimum required.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply . my question is will i get 3.3 v  and 200 mA  output by giving 5v as input. because in datasheet it is given like output voltage max 5v and output current max 200 mA . is that telling like if i get 5 v as output then only i will get 200 mA or i can able to get 200 mA with 3.3 v as output

Comment: Your previous question already covered that case when regulator is outputing 3.3V with 200mA maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum *recommended* junction temperature is 125°C so you're pretty marginal at 340mW, depending on the layout, number of layers, size of PCB and so on. If the temperature inside the enclosure gets above 45-55°C it would be easy to exceed the 125°C. Check that your 200mA is a real number. If it's more like 100mA then you're probably fine.

The power dissipation of any linear regulator will be the same, plus a bit for internal use, so really your concern is the specifications and the package and how you are going to design the device to safely dissipate that amount of power.

Note that you don't actually require an "LDO" regulator, since 5V - 3.3V is 1.7V. An LM1117 or similar [AMS1117-3.3](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) in SOT-223 or TO-252 package might be a better choice. If you don't want to, or can't, do all the testing and simulation for a relatively accurate thermal design it's better to be err on the safe side and use a bigger package with some copper on the tab.

As with any regulator of this type pay careful attention to the **value** and **type** (eg. tantalum) of output capacitor. The older LM1117 type can use a ceramic output capacitor safely if you add a series resistor.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply . after the consideration of thermal power consumption . I looked in to the data sheet of Lt3063    will it be perfect for my specification https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3063fa.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Each line in the datasheet table is separate.

If your input voltage is between \$V_{FB}\$ and 5 V you are not violating the input voltage specification.

If your output current is between 0 and 200 mA you are not violating the output current specification.

As another answer pointed out, there is also a thermal power consumption specification that you need to consider, and that might be harder to meet than these specs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply . after the consideration of thermal power consumption . I looked in to the data sheet of Lt3063  https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3063fa.pdf  will it be perfect for my specification